# xcode 8.3.3 or 9 does not show auto completion whenever adding any Entity to core data model file

Tags: xcode, autocomplete, autosuggest

I have tried the followings:

removing derived data, clean up project, restart - doesn't work

change deployment target to latest - doesn't work

turn off and on setting in Text Editing - no luck
....

and then I tried to delete the core data (.xcdatamodeld) file and recompile, it works magically! And then I add the core data file back, add an Entity to it, compile, does not work again! Magically when I delete it again, it works again!

Anyone has any idea?

By the way, this is macOS project, not iOS.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just right click and delete the xcdatamodelid file, and add it back, then add it to Copy Bundle Resources list, then it works fine...